# Solving $\int \sqrt{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int \sqrt{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3dx $$
I tried to solve this by using substitution. However, I could not reach the answer.
I tried to replace $1+\sqrt{x} = u$ and
$\sqrt{x} = u$
But still did not get the answer.I don't want to open parenthesis and solve integral in that way.

Comment: Do you mean $$\int \sqrt{x} \cdot \left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3\;?$$

Comment: Yes,thanks for correcting

Comment: Mutliply out the cube to get four terms. Multiply through by the square root. Then you have an easy sum of powers.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't want to simply open the parenthesis.

Comment: Why exactly would you not want to expand the integrand?

Comment: If you do a substitution you will still have parentheses that need opening: you may get three rather than four terms, but at the cost of the substitution, and for an indefinite integral the cost of re-substitution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{x}+1 \implies  \mathrm{d}x = 2\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}u$. It will then be $x = (u-1)^2$. Thus, the integral becomes :

$$\int (u-1)^2u^3\mathrm{d}u ={\displaystyle\int}u^5\,\mathrm{d}u-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{2}}{\displaystyle\int}u^4\,\mathrm{d}u+{\displaystyle\int}u^3\,\mathrm{d}u =\dfrac{u^6}{6}-\dfrac{2u^5}{5}+\dfrac{u^4}{4} + C $$

Now, substitute for $u= \sqrt{x} + 1$ and you should get for the initial integral :

\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x}) \mathrm{d}x &=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^6}{3}-\dfrac{4\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^5}{5}+\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^4}{2} + C\\
&= \boxed{\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^4\left(10x-4\sqrt{x}+1\right)}{30}+C}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can we try $ x^{\frac{-1}{2}}+1=u $ by taking $\sqrt{x}$ common

Comment: @LakshyaSinha What?

Comment: Take $ \sqrt{x} $ common from cubic term and suppose that as u

Comment: The person who disliked would be kind enough to point out ? The solution is perfectly clear and correct.

Answer (score 0):

By parts $u=(1+\sqrt{x})^3$ and $v'=\sqrt{x}$:

$$\int \sqrt{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3-\int \:x\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^2dx$$

And then by expanding:
$$\int \:x\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^2dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{4}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}+\frac{x^3}{3}$$

So
$$\int \sqrt{x}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)^3-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{4}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{x^3}{3}+C.$$